# Array of reference (or pointer) to labels in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Say I have a form with a long bunch of temperature readouts, so in the designer:

```
this.lblTemperatureDevice01 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.lblTemperatureDevice02 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.lblTemperatureDevice03 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
// ...
this.lblTemperatureDevice50 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
```

In the main form code, how do I add the labels to an array so that I can update the labels using a loop in a timer event eg:

```
private void tmrUpdateLabels_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Disable timer
    tmrUpdateLabels.Enabled = false;
    if (m_bExiting)
        return;

    // Update temperatures (if device has returned a reading)
    for (int device = 0; device < MAX_DEVICES; device++)
    {
        if (m_aHasNewReading[device])
        {
            m_aHasNewReading[device] = false;
            labels[device].Text = m_aTemperature[device].ToString();
        }
    }

    // Restart timer
    tmrUpdateLabels.Enabled = true;
}
```

How do I create the labels[MAX_DEVICES] array? Must I use:

```
private Label[] labels = new Label[MAX_DEVICES];
```

or is there a way to get a reference (or pointer) to the existing label(s) without creating new labels? Coming from a C++ background where I might have simply stored the address of each label in an array.

Comment: the Labels *are* references. `Label copy = lblTemperatureDevice01;` - `copy` points to the same object as `lbl...01`

Comment: `new Label[]` is creating just the array, not the `Label`s themselves. The only thing with value semantics in .NET are value types - primitives (`string` being an exception), `struct`s.

Comment: You did go pretty badly off the deep end when you used the designer to put 50 labels on the form.  Programmers never do anything more than twice.  Throw this away and start over.  If you don't know what code to write then first look at the way the designer did it.  Then just do *once* what it did 50 times.

Comment: My comment refers to your sentence: *is there a way to get a reference (or pointer) to the existing label(s) **without creating new labels?***, i.e. where would you create new Labels in your existing code?

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you mean create the labels in the main form code rather than add them through the designer? Come to think of it, that's a much better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create just two of these labels with the designer.

See what the designer produced.

Create a loop which creates an array of labels in your program, just after `InitializeComponents();`

Throw all the code from the desgner (for these labels) away.

Answer (score 2):

you can take all labels from Controls collection of the form

```
private Label[] labels;
.ctor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
            .Where(lbl => lbl.Name.StartsWith("lblTemperatureDevice"))
            .OrderBy(lbl => int.Parse(lbl.Name.Replace("lblTemperatureDevice","")))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Omitting OrderBy() is a very bad idea.